# Mapping on HTML escaping function in python

Tags: python, escaping, mapping

I have the following function in Python:

```
def escape_html(s):
    for(i, o) in (("&", "&amp;"),
                  (">", "&gt;"),
                  (">", "&gt;"),
                  (">", "&gt;")):
        s = s.replace(i,o)
    return s

print escape_html('"hello, & = &amp;"')
```

I dont understand those **"i" and "o"** variables in the **for**

Could someone please help to understand how this works ?

Thanks !

Comment: in the first iteration i = "&" and o = "&amp;" , also your syntax is not correct.

Comment: @dnit13 thanks, i just copied and pasted it from an udacity course. what is wrong with the syntax? the indentation?

Comment: Are you asking about tuple unpacking, or are you asking about how `str.replace()` works?

Comment: @dnit13 no, they aren't.

Comment: @Robᵩ I dont understand how the function actually makes its job. I am guessing the replace function goes character after character (?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand tuple unpacking. We're iterating over a tuple of tuples, so each iteration yields one of the inner tuples. Each of those tuples has two elements, so they can be conveniently unpacked and assigned to two variables in one statement with some fancy syntax:

```
for pair in (("&", "&amp;"),
             (">", "&gt;"),
             (">", "&gt;"),
             (">", "&gt;")):
    print(pair)
    (i, o) = pair
    print(i)
    print(o)
```

Output:

```
('&', '&amp;')
&
&amp;
('>', '&gt;')
>
&gt;
('>', '&gt;')
>
&gt;
('>', '&gt;')
>
&gt;
```

Tuple unpacking can be done directly inside a for loop for even greater convenience:

```
for (i, o) in (("&", "&amp;"),
               (">", "&gt;"),
               (">", "&gt;"),
               (">", "&gt;")):
    print(i)
    print(o)
```

Output:

```
&
&amp;
>
&gt;
>
&gt;
>
&gt;
```

As for the `replace` method:

```
>>> help('abc'.replace)
Help on built-in function replace:

replace(...) method of builtins.str instance
    S.replace(old, new[, count]) -> str

    Return a copy of S with all occurrences of substring
    old replaced by new.  If the optional argument count is
    given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

>>> 'abc def abc.'.replace('abc', '123')
'123 def 123.'
>>> s = '"hello, & = &amp;"'
>>> s = s.replace("&", "&amp;")
>>> s
'"hello, &amp; = &amp;amp;"'
```